# Google SignIn Status Codes

Tags: android, google-signin, google-play-games

This is my whole code for test sign in with google play services 
the problem is the

```
result.getStatus().getStatusCode()

return  codestatus ..... 12501
```

i don;t know why ?????

i did my connection on

1 https://firebase.google.com

2 https://play.google.com/apps/publish

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 9003;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            startSignInIntent();
        }
    }

    private void startSignInIntent() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .build();
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.default_web_client_id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
        Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+result.getStatus().getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // The signed in account is stored in the result.
                GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            } else {
                String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
                if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                    message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
                }
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Official Docs

[**`getStatusCode()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status#getStatusCode())

Indicates the status of the operation.

**Returns**

- Status code resulting from the operation. The value is one of the constants in CommonStatusCodes or specific to the APIs added to the GoogleApiClient.

[**CommonStatusCodes**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes)

```
CommonStatusCodes
public class CommonStatusCodes extends Object
Known Direct Subclasses
```

> Common status codes that are often shared across API surfaces.

**Constant Summary**

```
int     API_NOT_CONNECTED                   The client attempted to call a method from an API that failed to connect.
int     CANCELED                            The result was canceled either due to client disconnect or cancel().
int     DEVELOPER_ERROR                     The application is misconfigured.
int     ERROR                               The operation failed with no more detailed information.
int     INTERNAL_ERROR                      An internal error occurred.
int     INTERRUPTED                         A blocking call was interrupted while waiting and did not run to completion.
int     INVALID_ACCOUNT                     The client attempted to connect to the service with an invalid account name specified.
int     NETWORK_ERROR                       A network error occurred.
int     RESOLUTION_REQUIRED                 Completing the operation requires some form of resolution.
int     SERVICE_DISABLED                    This constant was deprecated. This case handled during connection, not during API requests. No results should be returned with this status code.
int     SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED     This constant was deprecated. This case handled during connection, not during API requests. No results should be returned with this status code.
int     SIGN_IN_REQUIRED                    The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in.
int     SUCCESS                             The operation was successful.
int     SUCCESS_CACHE                       The operation was successful, but was used the device's cache.
int     TIMEOUT                             Timed out while awaiting the result.
```